# is it possible to catch more than just email and password when trying to create a new user in Firebase?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Alright so I have the following code which works perfectly fine

```
const register = (e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
            if((email !== "" & (password !== "" & confirmsPassword !== "" )) & (firstName === "" || lastName === "" || phone === "" || id === "")){
                alert("Todos los campos son obligatorios")
            }
            else {
                auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then((auth) => {
                    if(auth.user){
                            auth.user.updateProfile({
                                displayName: firstName + " " + lastName,
                            }).then((s) => {
                                db.collection('usuarios').doc(auth.user.uid).set({
                                isAdmin: false,
                                displayName: auth.user.displayName,
                                name: firstName,
                                lastName: lastName,
                                email: auth.user.email,
                                phone: parseFloat(phone),
                                idType: idType,
                                id: id,
                                password: password,
                                uid: auth.user.uid,
                                photoURL: `${AIBLogo}`,
                                }).then((r) => {
                                    history.push("/")
                                })
                            })
                    }
                }).catch((e) => 
                {
                    if(firstName === "" & lastName ===""){
                        setMessage("Por favor escriba su nombre y apellido")
                        setError(true);
                    }
                    
                    else if(firstName === ""){
                        setMessage("Por favor escriba su nombre")
                        setError(true);
                    }
                    else if(lastName === ""){
                        setMessage("Por favor escriba su apellido")
                        setError(true);
                    }
            
                    else if(email === ""){
                        setMessage("Por favor escriba su correo electronico")
                        setError(true);
                    }
    
                    else if (e.message === "The email address is already in use by another account.") 
                    {
                        setMessage("La dirección de correo electrónico ya está siendo utilizada por otra cuenta.")
                        setError(true);
                    }
        
                    else if (e.message === "The email address is badly formatted.") 
                    {
                        setMessage("La dirección de correo electrónico está mal formateada")
                        setError(true);
                    }
            
                    else if(phone === ""){
                        setMessage("Por favor escriba su telefono celular o de casa")
                        setError(true);
                    }
            
                    else if(id === "" & idType === "Cédula"){
                        setMessage("Por favor introduzca su cédula")
                        setError(true);
                    }
            
                    else if(id === "" & idType === "Pasaporte"){
                        setMessage("Por favor introduzca su pasaporte")
                        setError(true);
                    }
            
                    else if(id === ""){
                        setMessage("Por favor introduzca su cédula o pasaporte")
                        setError(true);
                    }
            
                    else if(password === ""){
                        setMessage("Por favor introduzca su contraseña")
                        setError(true);
                    }
            
                    else if(password !== confirmsPassword){
                        setMessage("Las contraseñas no coinciden")
                        setError(true);
                    }
            
                    else if(password.length < 6){
                        setMessage("Su contraseña debe tener al menos 6 caracteres")
                        setError(true);
                    }
                });
            }  

        setError(false);
    }
```

However I'm forced to add an if statement before the firebase arguments because in my form if let's say I fill the email and password and leave all the other fields in blank it will go through  and create an user with only those 2 pieces of information (email and password).

I want to know if there's a work around because my Alerts from MUI only do work if they get called by a catch argument, they don't get call in the first if statement before the firebase argument (which is why I have a basic Alert there instead of setting up message and error only like my other conditions inside the catch)

Just want to know if is possible to catch more arguments or is just email and password.

Edit:

**Form code as requested**

```
return (
        <Container fixed >
            <Paper component="form" elevation = {3} style = {paperStyle} >
                <Box sx={{textAlign:'center'}}>
                <img src= {AIBLogo} className = "register_logo" />
                <Typography gutterBottom variant="h5" component="div"> Registrar Usuario </Typography>
                <Typography variant="overline" color="text.secondary"> rapido y sencillo </Typography>
                </Box>

            <Box sx={{display: 'grid', gridTemplateColumns: { md: '1fr 1fr' }, gap: 1,}}>

            <TextField required onChange={handleChangeName} margin="dense" label='Nombre' /> 
            <TextField required onChange={handleChangeLastName} margin="dense" label='Apellido' /> 
            <TextField required onChange={handleChangeEmail} margin="dense" label='Correo Electrónico' /> 
            <TextField required inputProps={{ type: 'number'}} onChange={handleChangePhone} margin="dense" label='Teléfono' /> 
            
            <TextField
               required
               select
               margin="dense"
               onChange={handleChangeIdType}
               value = {idType}
               helperText="Cédula o Pasaporte"
               >
                   {documents.map((option) => (
                   <MenuItem key={option.value} value={option.value}>
                       {option.label}
                    </MenuItem>
                ))}
            </TextField>

            <TextField required onChange={handleChangeID} margin="dense" label='Identificacion' /> 

            <TextField required onChange={handleChangePassword} margin="dense" label='Contraseña - min 6 Digitos' 
            type={showPassword1 ? "text" : "password"}
            InputProps={{ // <-- This is where the toggle button is added.
                endAdornment: (
                  <InputAdornment position="end">
                    <IconButton
                      aria-label="toggle password visibility"
                      onClick={handleClickShowPassword1}
                      onMouseDown={handleMouseDownPassword1}
                    >
                      {showPassword1 ? <Visibility /> : <VisibilityOff />}
                    </IconButton>
                  </InputAdornment>
                )
              }}/> 
              
            <TextField required onChange={handleChangeConfirmPassword} margin="dense" label='Verificar contraseña' 
            type={showPassword2 ? "text" : "password"}
            InputProps={{ // <-- This is where the toggle button is added.
                endAdornment: (
                  <InputAdornment position="end">
                    <IconButton
                      aria-label="toggle password visibility"
                      onClick={handleClickShowPassword2}
                      onMouseDown={handleMouseDownPassword2}
                    >
                      {showPassword2 ? <Visibility /> : <VisibilityOff />}
                    </IconButton>
                  </InputAdornment>
                )
              }}/> 
              
        </Box>
              
            <Box pt = {2} sx={{textAlign:'center'}}>
                <Button type = "submit" onClick={register} variant = "contained" color = "primary" size = "large" type="submit" > 
                Registrar 
                </Button>
                <Box m = {1}>
                    <Link href="/" underline="hover" variant = "overline">
                        {'¿Ya tiene una cuenta?'}
                    </Link>
                    </Box>  
            </Box>
        </Paper>
        {error ?  <Alertas message = {message} /> : `` }
        </Container>
    )
```

it looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Why don't you mark all the fields as required from your ReactJS code and call this procedure onSubmit? This way the function won't trigger unless all the required inputs are set and you can remove all your if-else chain. If I understood correctly at least. Remember to preventDefault to prevent the page from reloading on submit.

Comment: I have them as required but for some reason it doesn't work. This is an example of how I have them: `<TextField required onChange={handleChangeName} margin="normal" label='Student Name' /> `

Comment: you can do that of course, but you cannot store it in firebase auth instead you should store it in firebase firestore databse, firebase auth only accepts email and password and the only idea behind this is to not keep the password in your own database but keep it in a more more secure place which is managed by google

Comment: Then check that the button you press to confirm is of type "submit" and all the field are enclosed within a form tag. If you're using a custom input from some framework check their documentation to see how you should do to make it required. Some call the prop isRequired, others required, others something else.

Comment: @Bafforasta ah I was missing the type submit I'll check that. Edit: It still went through, by having email and password and all the other fields in blank it still went through and created an user with only those 2 fields even though I have required on everything and `type = "submit"` on the button

Comment: @webcoder I'm storing everything on the firestore as a document

Comment: Could you post your form code? Also, are you using some custom component? I don't remember HTML5 having a native TextField tag, but I might be wrong.

Comment: I'm using MUI for everything @Bafforasta

Comment: please have a close look at this [link] (https://github.com/hidjou/classsed-react-firebase-functions/blob/master/functions/handlers/users.js), even though it is backend but frontend is similar

Comment: I'll read into it @webcoder

Comment: @ReactPotato OK apparently the way you're making it required is correct according to MUI documentation. I would replace all the &s in the first if with ||, replace all the !== with === and remove every bracket except the first and final one. This should not allow you to create an account.

Comment: I can't do that, the thing is, that by only having the email and password it can go through to create an account which is why I said: if email and password are not BLANK and any other value is = to BLANK then call an alert saying: all fields are required however if the person try to do the form as a normal person lol the catch works. The catch get calls if email or password are empty cause those are the 2 parameters that `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` takes. Yes required is correct according to MUI but it doesn't work at all which is annoying.

Comment: @ReactPotato alright then. If that's what you want to achieve the logic is correct. However the correct way to express the logic and is to use && while & performs a bitwise and. You should replace all the single & with double &s. Also open an issue on the MUI git page explaining that TextField's required prop doesn't work properly when in a Paper with role=form.

Comment: Also, looking at the code, the 'register' procedure shouldn't be called onClick but onSubmit (applied to the form, not to the button), otherwise form validation won't work.

Comment: Oh that worked omg I can remove so much code lmao

Comment: @ReactPotato, if you find the comment helpful, kindly post it as an answer as it would help the community a lot.